# Low(?) entropy available on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, random, pidgin

I just had some problems to get Pidgin with OTR running, because Pidgin hung on every attempt to generate my private key.
[This](http://xunlinkx.blogspot.de/2009/11/pidgin-otr-and-random-number-generation.html) rather old blog post pointed me into the right direction (or rather "allowed me to generate a key"), by "feeding /dev/urandom into the entropy pool for /dev/random".

When I do `watch cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`, I see numbers < 50. While feeding /dev/urandom into the entropy pool, this number went up to ~2000 and then I was able to generate my key.

Are my entropy values of < 50 bit(?) normal? I'm on a desktop system with basically Firefox, Thunderbird and Pidgin running, streaming music from LAN.

Is the inability to create a key for OTR a bug in Pidgin or is my Arch Linux installation to blame for the low entropy?

PS: I know about [this answer explaining many misconceptions about entropy and (P)RNGs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42952/how-can-i-measure-and-increase-entropy-on-mac-os-x/42955#42955).

**Update:** There already are open bugs at [the OTR bugtracker](https://bugs.otr.im/issues/63) and at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pidgin/+bug/303862) about this issue. Writing random text in an editor also helps when generating the key.

Comment: I tested on a couple of Ubuntu systems (one with pretty heavy use, the other mostly idle), and both had values of ~800.

Comment: Ok, I tested it on 98 Ubuntu systems that I could connect to (all of which are mostly idle). The average, median, min and max vales were: 651.602, 711, 147, 906. Never as low as 50. I think this is a systemic problem (and not one in Pidgin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Feeding `/dev/urandom` into the entropy pool for `/dev/random`” is cheating — you're pretending to provide new entropy when in fact the data is derived deterministically from the current state of the RNG. Fortunately, [as you noted](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42952/how-can-i-measure-and-increase-entropy-on-mac-os-x/42955#42955), the rule that you're cheating is a useless one: entropy doesn't actually decrease despite what the Linux kernel pretends.

Low entropy by Linux's `/dev/random`'s estimate is common and almost always a false alarm: the estimate is unreasonably conservative.

[`/dev/urandom` is secure for key generation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939), so Pidgin should arguably use `/dev/urandom` (which doesn't block) instead of `/dev/random` (which can block, and often does).

There is only one case where `/dev/random` blocking is legitimate because the system genuinely doesn't have enough entropy: when the system is too new to have accumulated entropy. Linux systems normally save entropy for the next reboot, so in practice genuine low entropy only happens in two circumstances:

- on a brand new installation — this is especially a concern in embedded devices that generate a key the first time they're turned on;
- on a live system.

Where to set the blame isn't really a productive consideration, but if you must: Arch Linux and you are fully innocent. Pidgin should use `/dev/urandom` or at least offer a way, so it gets part of the blame. The Linux kernel should really provide an interface that's guaranteed to deliver crypto-quality randomness and blocks only if entropy is genuinely lacking (like FreeBSD's `/dev/random`).

Comment: "Arch Linux and you are fully innocent." But according to the comments on my question, somehow has (reports?) more entropy than my box...

Comment: @Jasper If you've been using `/dev/random` a lot (perhaps you tried Pidgin's key generation several times?) then your entropy level will be low. It never gets really high even when it's had a lot of time to accumulate, so it can deplete pretty quickly.

Comment: That might be the case. Now I'm getting ~1000 entropy from entropy_avail.